# View photos in Windows 10 withtout border

Tags: windows-10, windows-photo-viewer

I would like to view photos in Windows 10. Unfortunately, when I double click on a photo it is displayed in a window of the Photos app with a black border. However, I don't want to waste space for a borer but I only want to see my photo as large as possible.

How can I get rid of the border?

(Switching back and forth between full screen and window mode is annoying because of the additional key strokes and therefore not an option for me.)

Comment: Since this thread still comes up at the top of google searches... the solution I found for this is [PureRef](https://www.pureref.com/). It's marketed to graphic designers but is basically a borderless image viewer. As of december 2023, the software is free with an optional donation

Answer (score 2):

Third-party tools such as [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) give more options for viewing photos. You can double-click on a photo in that application to view one full screen, and as you advance, others will be shown that way. There are also options for setting view to the image *width* or image *height*, whether to show *all* full-screen or only high-resolution photos, etc.

Of course, if the image is not the same *ratio* as the display, there will be black borders at edges or at top and bottom, unless you expand and crop the image to match the display (e.g. 1.777... for 1080p).